# Oracle 10g not able to connect to database instance

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

The machine was assigned a DHCP address so I had to install and configure the Microsoft Loopback Adapter before installing 10g. It installed without errors or warnings and I'm able to ping the adapter IP address. I also configured a TCP listener through the net configuration assistant to the default port 1521. I then created a database and configured it using the wizard but now when I try to connect to it from SQL Plus it gives me this error:

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.
```

The TNSNAMES.ORA file is automatically generated and nothing seems to be wrong with it. What could be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a very silly mistake. The name maxprodtest was too long and so the listener identifier was shortened automatically to maxprodt.